# How to make Android specific code compatible with IOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, compatibility

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#e7e7e7" />
  <solid android:color="#fafafa" />
  <padding android:left="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:top="1dp" />
  <corners android:radius="30dp" />
</shape>
```

**Xml code for Custom Renderer above.**

```
public class CustomRoundedEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.Background = Android.App.Application.Context.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.RoundedEntry);
                Control.Gravity = GravityFlags.CenterVertical;
                Control.SetPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Custom renderer code in android solution.**

What needed here is that this code should be compatible and can be run with iOS platform also.

Comment: Same way write Custom render for iOS, but there no drawable file option, 
The Alternative way use CALayer for Style options. go through this linkhttps://dzone.com/articles/xamarinforms-borderless-entry-using-custom-rendere

Comment: @logeshpalani98 I already created for android and it is working. I need to make this work on iOS

Comment: it won't work. you should write separately for iOS.

Comment: @logeshpalani98 Dude, I am asking that "How can I make it compatible ?" as you can read above.

Comment: bro it will work, no problem.

Comment: @Bysalyanman, you've got a proper advice here. It is just like if you wrote the app for Android in Android Studio and now you want to run the app on XCode on iOS. There is no magic but hard work and if you don't want to do the hard work on your project no one else will do it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to set the **Border** and **Corner** of Entry by using Custom Renderer .

For iOS , you can check the following code

```
public class MyEntryRenderer:EntryRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if(Control!=null)
        {
            Control.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;

            //border and corner
            Control.Layer.BorderColor = Color.FromHex("#e7e7e7").ToCGColor();
            Control.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
            Control.Layer.CornerRadius = 30;

            //padding
            UIView padView = new UIView() {Frame = new CGRect(0,0,10,1)};
            Control.LeftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
            Control.LeftView = padView;

        }
    }
```